# C# Show webp in Picturebox with both animated and static .webp files

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, webp

I have a bunch of .webp files on my disk. I now want to show these files in a picturebox inside of my WinForm application (one after the other). Converting webp to bitmaps works. The problem is that some of the webp files are animated.

The app should be capable to see if a webp file is static or animated and should convert it to something that can be shown in the picturebox.

This is my current Code to show static webp file:

```
Imazen.WebP.SimpleDecoder decoder = new Imazen.WebP.SimpleDecoder();
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
var bitmap = decoder.DecodeFromBytes(bytes, bytes.Length);
pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

This uses a wrapper for libwebp. But I am totally fine with different resources/libraries. Most methods mentioned on the web demand that you already know the target type (f.e. gif jpg etc). Any input in appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [System.Drawing.Animator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imageanimator.animate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) class. It works for GIFs, but in theory any bitmap supporting animation (Bitmap.CanAnimate) should be supported. You need to manually set timers and tasks in order to paint the frames at the specified times.

Having said that, at first glance it doesn't look like your [library of choice](https://github.com/imazen/libwebp-net/blob/master/src/Imazen.WebP/SimpleDecoder.cs) handles animated bitmaps.

Comment: In fact, animation is one of the things in their "TO DO" list.